# Scheduled triggers wont work in a dependeny build configuration

Tags: version-control, triggers, dependencies, teamcity

I have 3 projects A, B, C. C=>B and B=>A. I have a scheduled trigger attached in build C. Which when executed manually works fine but it is not triggering the scheduled one at specified time.

[image]

Also please see how it is working fine if executed manually. Please guide what I am missing here. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the option `Trigger build only if there are pending changes` on the Trigger for Build `C` and see if that makes it go when the time is hit.

Comment: So does build C just not run at all or does B not fire after C and A after B?

Comment: If branch filter is empty then it will execute using default branch and if I try to use any logical branch in it then it wont execute at all.

Comment: Try `+:%env.branchName%` for the branch filter

Comment: I tried passing the full logical name of branch and -:<default> for any thing but not default and guess it works only with branch filter +:* ..Over the moon now as spent 2 days just to make this work.

Comment: Glad you got it working. That was going to be my next suggestion.